# Cardview is missing on some devices

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-activity, cardview

i create two cardview correctly but when i run on my phone card view activity is Right but when run in other phone card view is displace please help me to solve this problem

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt8E3.jpg)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.nima.ts.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="135dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="135dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="119dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to share your layout file.

Comment: Please share the xml code where this `CardView` is.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nagEx.png @Shaishav

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nagEx.png @IshitaSinha

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nagEx.png @Ishita Sinha

Comment: Don't share code via images. Use the 'edit' button towards the bottom-left of your post to add more relevant info. Also, visit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry Shaishav...when add my code. error write (its look like mostly code;put some more detail) what this error http://s2.picofile.com/file/8263725068/Screenshot_4_.png @Shaishav

Comment: You need to explain your problem in detail...what are you building (couple of activities, fragments, etc), what is the expected result and what is the issue...

Comment: thank you.. i added code .Please tell me where is my the problem @Shaishav

Comment: In your screenshot, which one is the correct one?

Comment: top phone @Shaishav

Comment: Ishita's answer should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added two `CardView`s side by side. According to your code, both are `layout_alignParentTop="true"`, which means that both will try to stick to the top of the parent `RelativeLayout` when enough horizontal room is available. However, this happens in neither of your devices, which is why they appear one below the other.

Please replace your code with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.nima.ts.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/card_view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: We can get rid of `android:layout_gravity="center"`... if view gravity is to be affected, we can use `android:gravity="center"`